# How to get the value of a textbox adjoining a button with gwt query

Tags: gwt, jquery-selectors, gwtquery, gquery

I have a custom widget like this, it's basically a couple of text boxes and buttons along with them.

```
<g:VerticalPanel>
    <b:Label>Lower Limit</b:Label>
    <b:TextBox ui:field="lowerLimit" addStyleNames="lowerLimitTextBox"></b:TextBox>
    <b:Button icon="COPY" addStyleNames="copyAll copyAllLower">Copy To All</b:Button>
</g:VerticalPanel>

<g:VerticalPanel>
    <b:Label>Upper Limit</b:Label>
    <b:TextBox ui:field="upperLimit" addStyleNames="upperLimitTextBox"></b:TextBox>
    <b:Button icon="COPY" addStyleNames="copyAll copyAllUpper">Copy To All</b:Button>
 </g:VerticalPanel>
```

There are many of these widgets on a page.
When a button is clicked I want to be able to select the text box to it's left and copy that value to all the corresponding widgets.

I can select the buttons but don't know how to select the textbox to it's immediate left.
Can anyone help with this.

I'm adding the jQuery-selectors tag as the selector might be similar to that of GwtQuery.

Comment: Can you just get the `Element` for the `Button` (`Button#getElement`) and then get the previous sibling element for it (`Element#getPreviousSiblingElement`)? Perhaps you'd have to walk through more than one previous sibling?

Comment: GWT Query for me doesn't seem to have the get previous sibling element function.

Comment: Yes, gquery has the `prev()`. You have to be aware that `VerticalPanel` is wrapping your widgets with `tr` and `td` though. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you have to know how a `VerticalPanel` is rendered so as you can figure out where is the text box in the dom.

`VerticalPanel` is rendered as a table, and each widget is positioned into a structure: `<tr><td>widget</td></tr>`

In your case you can use `closest()` and `prev()` to get the previous `tr` of your button:

```java
$(button).closest("tr").prev();
```

Then use `find()` to get the `input` inside the previous `tr`

```java
$(button).closest("tr").prev().find("input")
```

So using the gquery ability of finding `Widgets`, the code for each button in your UI could look like:

```java
  button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      TextBox box = $(button).closest("tr").prev().find("input").widget();
      for (TextBox b :  $(".gwt-TextBox").widgets(TextBox.class) ) {
        b.setValue(box.getValue());
      }
    }
  });
```

Although if you wanted to use `gquery` to enhance all buttons at once, everything is much simpler:

```java
  $(".gwt-Button").click(new Function(){
    public void f() {
      String value = $(this).closest("tr").prev().find("input").val();
      $(".gwt-TextBox").val(value);
    }
  });
```